# saving strings to isolated storage and after downloading new ones refreshing the old ones

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

i have downloaded some json with webclient and saved it to isolated storage after deserialization as strings. so they are saved now and i show them up by the application start because the webclient downloads them, so after the download they are still there how can i refresh them with the new downloaded data and not to interrupt them so that the dont blink.

i have this code :

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if (!settings.Contains("temp"))
{
    settings.Add("temp", tempTextBlock.Text.ToString());
}
else
{
    settings["temp"] = tempTextBlock.Text.ToString();
}
```

to save temp to iso. i use them on the "OnNavigatedTo" so i see them when the app starts but they stay there even after the download of the data in the background. what can i do to just refresh this string i saved with the new data that is downloaded? is there some method to compare the data and then display just the newer one?

here is the code:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            DayList = new ObservableCollection<List>();
            DayList.Add(new List { Time = DateTime.Now, weather = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Weather> { new Weather { icon = "01d", description = "sunćano" } }, main = new Main {temp = 8 } });
            DayList.Add(new List { Time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), weather = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Weather> { new Weather { icon = "01d", description = "sunćano" } }, main = new Main { temp = 10 } });
            DayList.Add(new List { Time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), weather = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Weather> { new Weather { icon = "01d", description = "sunćano" } }, main = new Main { temp = 6 } });
            CurrentDay = DayList[0];
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("temp"))
            {
```

here i want to check if the saved string is newer or the number is different then the new one downlaoded right now. the problem is this code here persists after the download anddont change on an another download later. because of no comparing :(
                }
                else
                {
                }

```
        }
    }
```

and i use this as the download completes to show the data on the MainPage...

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
            DayList = new ObservableCollection<List>(json.list);
            CurrentDay = DayList[0];
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that in isolated settings , if you using Static strings then isolated settings will not work as it is created that when app starts, so if you change afterwards it just stores , but never used until startup again,

Isolated storage is for secure the data not for passing or storing purpose

Comment: yes i want to save it on the same key so it works every time no how far in the future. i save this key when it is loaded so it is in an textBlock named tempTextBlock i trigger this method above when this textblock is "LayoutUpdated" event handler. and i want to compare them at the first lines of code, so this is in the mvvm MainViewModel.cs there is an peace for if its (IsInDesignMode) i use the else{} but how to compare the two?! any example how to do? and the other problem is how to set the newer one to display after this comparing?

Comment: so i added the code above, you can see the method that is calling right when the app starts thats the public MainViewModel(){...}

and the code underneath it shows the methos as the download completes, then it is displayed on the MainPage, there in the code behind i save it like the first code snippet. and if the app is opened an second time it should display these strins i saved, then after the download just fade in the new downloaded data without to interrupt the data on the mainpage visibly. right now the problem is i open the app and i see nothing before the download.

Comment: @dinchy87 now check my answer

Comment: yeah but i use static strings like "temp" it saves me an string like "10" to IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings and i want just to display this saved string until the data is downloaded in the MainViewModel after that the downloaded string should be visible.

i meant this only to show up as the download method is downloading in the background. how can do this?

Comment: @dinchy87 so what you want to do can you explain with screenshot